# How to programmatically insert a <link rel="import"> in the context of web component?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create a custom component using webcomponents.js only, not the full Polymer library. I have managed to create some, but have a problem with this one. This component is a variant of the HTML`<link>`tag. Instead of having a valid URL in the href attribute, it has a string that will be processed to produce a valid URL. Example:

```
<!-- "variable" will be replaced to produce a valid URL -->
<my-link href="http://example.com/{{variable}}.html" >
```

I process this web component, adding a link in the DOM using a valid URL with a javascript code like:

```
var link = document.createElement('LINK');
link.rel = "import";
link.href = processMyLinkHref();
this.appendChild(link);
```

That link is correctly retrieved later with a `doc.querySelectorAll('link[rel="import"]');`instruction. But the DOM corresponding to the imported file that should be there, and I can get it if I use a regular `<link rel="import">`tag, is unavailable in the `import` attribute of the link object.

It looks like that the ressource has not been fetched by the browser. I tried to look in the source of webcomponents.js, found calls to `handleImport`javascript functions through closures, but my knowlegde of javascript is not good enough to really understand what goes on here.

So here is the question: how do I make the browser fetch the imported file just like it was a regular HTML `<link>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My javascript knowledge is better now, and I understand the problem. Contrary to what I wrote, the ressource is fetched when the link node is inserted. But it's content is not stored anywhere. You have to do this manually. It's a little bit strange, but...

The code that works is:

```
// Create a new import node
var importNode = document.createElement('link');
importNode.href= href;
importNode.rel= 'import';
// Set the callback used when import is loaded. The line below is
// adapted from importHref function in Polymer
importNode.onload = importLoaded.bind(this, importNode);
// Triggers import loading
document.head.appendChild(importNode);
```

And the callback code is:

```
var importLoaded = function (importNode, event) {
    // Put the document DOM tree in the import attribute as usual
    importNode.import = event.target.import;
};
```

You can use importHref in your own code, but I wanted to insert a `<link rel"import">` code just as if it was written in the page source code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a disclaimer that I'm not fully sure what you've got going on in your question description, but to generally answer the question title & perhaps the overall question have you seen:

`importHref(href, onload, onerror).`

which dynamically imports an HTML document. You can find some more info about it here - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have already seen that function, looked at its source and its exactly what I'm doing in my code. I think there is something else done somewhere by Polymer (that I don't want to use :-) ) that make it work, and it's that "something else"  I'm looking for.